# How to see XML output of SOAP request via vendor API using WordPress/Woocommerce

Tags: xml, wordpress, soap, wsdl, woocommerce

I'm more of a designer with some front-end development skills taking on a role that involves more backend development then I'm comfortable with. I inherited a WP site that uses Woocommerce. The previous developer built a custom payment plugin to process orders with our fulfillment house using their SOAP API.

In order to test that all data is being transmitted properly, I've been instructed to use the SOAP Client of my choice, and place test orders to see the XML output of those orders.

When I export orders from Woocommerce directly, I only see Woocommerce fields – I don't see any of the fulfillment house's fields.

Can someone please explain, in the simplest language how I can see a full XML output of the data being sent via the API?

I have the WSDL address and login credentials but I have no idea what to do with them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use client like [Wizdler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wizdler/oebpmncolmhiapingjaagmapififiakb) on chrome and query the WSDL URL using the credentials you have. You will get an XML response which you can analyse

Here are a few other options

[SOA Client](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/soa-client/) - works well with firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Jude. I have a couple questions:

1. Will these work even though the API I'm using is SOAP not REST?
2. The WSDL URL is hosted by the fulfilment house, so how does the data I'm entering into the form itself enter the equation?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the links, you can send your form data as part of your request body or RAW WSDL data as shown in the samples